# md-data-table Sorting Desc empty cells are shown first

Tags: angular-material

Is there any way i could **make the empty cells NOT show up first on Desc Sort ?**

The tag for this should be [md-data-table](https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table), but i there isn't any, so a added angular-material.

[Working Pen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dvdRpr?editors=1010)

[image: asc]

[image: desc]

**Code Snippet**

```
<tr md-row md-select="dessert" ng-repeat="dessert in desserts.data | filter: filter.search | orderBy: query.order | limitTo: query.limit : (query.page -1) * query.limit">
    <td md-cell>{{dessert.calories.value}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: your code snippets affects only when you order by pressing dessert header, you will have to do the same for calories header. Or find a general better solution.

Comment: I would appreciate an example or a CodePen if you can. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, the Code Snippet may not be so eloquent. Look at the Working Pen Example posted in the question for the whole thing.